# Capture the controls' OnPaint event for offline rendering

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I'm having a little bit trouble bringing together the old windows forms world and the WPF world. The original problem was that we always have to have a WindowsFormsHost for hosting our windows forms controls, especially the Chart control for displaying graphs.

Since we also have the need for client/server support, my idea was to create a windows form and add the Chart as a child. For this reason I created a OffscreenForm (BackEnd) which I shift to a location where the window is not visible (e.g. X=-10000, Y=-10000).

Then I attach my FrontEnd WPF control to a userdefined OnPaint method that updates everytime the BackEnd has changed. The problem in OnPaint is that is only renders the visible part. Therefore I took OnPrint, but DrawToImage has a memory bug and doesn't clean up correctly. I also transferred mouse events from the FrontEnd to the BackEnd.

In short words: Has someone ever tried to create something similar. Most of my current solution works fine, but there are minor things I don't really understand between OnPaint/OnPrint.

Here's my code. It looks currently a little bit ugly. Some of the things are only to see something when something happens.

It would be great if someone has a solution to get the image of the control when a refresh/repaint occurs.

Thanks
Martin

BackEnd:

```
using siemens.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace formshost
{
    public class OffscreenWindowsFormsRenderer : Control
    {
        public event EventHandler<MemoryStream> MyPaint;
        System.Windows.Forms.Form form = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();

        List<Point> pts = new List<Point>();

        int x = 10;
        public OffscreenWindowsFormsRenderer(Control ctrl)
            : base()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();

            form = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();
            form.CreateControl();
            form.SetBounds(-10000, 300, 0, 0, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified.Location);
            form.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.Manual;
            form.Show();
            form.Controls.Add(this);


            CreateControl();

            BackColor = Color.Lime;

            Controls.Add(ctrl);

            //FireImage();

            Timer T = new Timer();
            T.Tick += T_Tick;
            T.Start();
        }

        void T_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Refresh();
            x += 5;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, x, x, 50, 50);

            lock (pts)
            {
                if (pts.Count > 1)
                    e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Red, pts.ToArray());
            }

            FireImage();
        }

        protected override void OnPrint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPrint(e);        

            //FireImage();
        }

        Bitmap bmp;

        void FireImage()
        {

            lock (this)
            {
                int W = Width;
                int H = Height;

                if (bmp != null)
                {
                    if (bmp.Width != W || bmp.Height != H)
                    {
                        bmp.Dispose();
                        bmp = null;
                    }
                }

                if (bmp == null)
                {
                    if (W > 0 && H > 0)
                        bmp = new Bitmap(W, H, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                }

                if (bmp != null)
                {
                    DrawToBitmapExtended(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, W, H));
                    MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
                    bmp.Save(mem, ImageFormat.Bmp);

                    MyPaint(this, mem);
                }

                //    using(Graphics g
            }
        }

        protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnResize(e);
            FireImage();
        }

        protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSizeChanged(e);
            Refresh();            
        }

        public void MouseMove(IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
        {
            //Message msg = Message.Create(this.Handle, User.WM_MOUSEMOVE, wparam, lparam);
            SendMessage(this.Handle, User.WM_MOUSEMOVE, wparam, lparam);
            FireImage();
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);

            lock (pts)
            {
                pts.Add(e.Location);
            }
        }

        Bitmap tempimage;

        public void DrawToBitmapExtended(Bitmap bitmap, Rectangle targetBounds)
        {
            if (bitmap == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("bitmap");
            }

            if (targetBounds.Width <= 0 || targetBounds.Height <= 0
                || targetBounds.X < 0 || targetBounds.Y < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("targetBounds");
            }

            if (!IsHandleCreated)
            {
                CreateHandle();
            }


            int width = Math.Min(this.Width, targetBounds.Width);
            int height = Math.Min(this.Height, targetBounds.Height);

            if (tempimage != null)
            {
                if (tempimage.Width != width || tempimage.Height != height)
                {
                    tempimage.Dispose();
                    tempimage = null;
                }
            }

      //     if (tempimage == null)
                tempimage = new Bitmap(width, height, bitmap.PixelFormat);

                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempimage))
            {
                IntPtr hDc = g.GetHdc();

                //send the actual wm_print message
                SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_PRINT, (IntPtr)hDc,
                    (IntPtr)(PRF_CHILDREN | PRF_CLIENT | PRF_NONCLIENT ));

                //now BLT the result to the destination bitmap.

                using (Graphics destGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    IntPtr desthDC = destGraphics.GetHdc();
                    BitBlt(desthDC, targetBounds.X, targetBounds.Y, width, height,
                                             hDc, 0, 0, 0x00CC0020);
                    destGraphics.ReleaseHdc(desthDC);
                }
                g.ReleaseHdc(hDc);
            }
        }

        const int PRF_NONCLIENT = 0x00000002,
             PRF_CLIENT = 0x00000004,
             PRF_ERASEBKGND = 0x00000008,
        PRF_CHILDREN = 0x00000010,
        WM_PRINT = 0x0317,
        WM_PRINTCLIENT = 0x0318,
        PRF_OWNED = 0x0020;


        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        static extern int SetROP2(IntPtr hdc, int fnDrawMode);

        [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
        [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("Gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
        [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
        public static extern int BitBlt(IntPtr hDC, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight,
                                         IntPtr hSrcDC, int xSrc, int ySrc, int dwRop);

    }
}
```

FrontEnd:

```
using formshost;
using siemens.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication6
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        OffscreenWindowsFormsRenderer off;
        System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox box = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInitialized(e);

            PanelFast fast = new PanelFast();

            myGrid.Children.Add(fast);
            Grid.SetRow(fast, 1);

            box.Width = 100;
            box.Height = 100;
            box.Image = new Bitmap("D:\\image.jpg");
            //box.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            box.Show();


            off = new OffscreenWindowsFormsRenderer(box);
            off.Visible = true;

            fast.SetRenderer(off);
        }
    }

    public class PanelFast : Panel
    {
        public OffscreenWindowsFormsRenderer Renderer
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        BitmapImage myBitmap = null;

        public void SetRenderer(OffscreenWindowsFormsRenderer r)
        {
            Renderer = r;
            Renderer.MyPaint += off_MyPaint;
        }

        void off_MyPaint(object sender, MemoryStream e)
        {
            myBitmap = new BitmapImage();

            myBitmap.BeginInit();
            myBitmap.StreamSource = e;
            myBitmap.EndInit();
            myBitmap.Freeze();

            SnapsToDevicePixels = true;


            InvalidateVisual();
        }

        public PanelFast()
        {
            SizeChanged += PanelFast_SizeChanged;
        }

        void PanelFast_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Renderer.SetBounds(0, 0, (int)ActualWidth, (int)ActualHeight, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified.Size);
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            base.OnRender(dc);
            dc.DrawImage(myBitmap, new Rect(0, 0, ActualWidth, ActualHeight));
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);
            Renderer.MouseMove((IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)GetXY(e.GetPosition(this)));
        }

        int GetXY(System.Windows.Point pt)
        {
            int x = (int)(pt.X);
            int y = (int)(pt.Y);

            return y << 16 | x;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This all sounds like a horrible hack. Why don't you just use a WPF graph control instead of the winforms stuff?

Comment: @HighCore: You are indeed right. The current WPF graph control does unfortunately not support all th features the classic chartcontrol. Nevertheless it's not only about the chart control. We have many more classic control we need to rely on. The forms host kills many things (mousewheel, transparency). We have worked for hours now on this. For me it seems that thing I want to do solves many problems than embedding the winformshost.

Comment: which "classic controls"? whatever you need, I'm pretty sure it's way easier to implement it using WPF than resorting to dinosaur winforms.

Comment: Its about our own classic winforms controls. For our project there is currently no time to transfer everything to WPF. Do you know if the WPF Chart control has the same features as the win forms control?

Comment: you need to be specific about what features you're looking for. Also, whatever "classic controls" you might have in winforms I'm pretty sure they can be developed in WPF in no-time. winforms doesn't really support anything, so you can't really create complex stuff on it.